# How to add varying prefixes to strings in pandas column

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe with 2 columns containing audio filenames and corresponding texts, looking like this:

```
data = {'Audio_Filename': ['3e2bd3d1-b9fc-095728a4d05b', 
                           '8248bf61-a66d-81f33aa7212d', 
                           '81051730-8a18-6bf476d919a4'],
        'Text': ['On a trip to America, he saw people filling his noodles into paper cups.', 
                 'When the young officers were told they were going to the front,', 
                 'Yeah, unbelievable, I had not even thought of that.']}
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['Audio_Filename', 'Text'])
```

Now I want to add a string prefix (the speaker ID: `sp1`, `sp2`, `sp3`) with an underscore `_` to all audio filename strings according to this pattern:
`sp2_3e2bd3d1-b9fc-095728a4d05b`.

My difficulty: The prefix/speaker ID is not fixed but varies depending on the audio filenames. Because of this, I have zipped the audio filenames and the speaker IDs and iterated over those and the audio filename rows via for-loops. This is my code:

```
zipped = list(zip(audio_filenames, speaker_ids))

for audio, speaker_id in zipped:
    for index, row in df.iterrows():
        audio_row = row['Audio_Filename']
             if audio == audio_row:
                 df['Audio_Filename'] = f'{speaker_id}_' + audio_row
                 df.to_csv('/home/user/file.csv')
```

I also tried `apply` with `lambda` after the `if` statement:

```
df['Audio_Filename'] = df['Audio_Filename'].apply(lambda x: '{}_{}'.format(speaker_id, audio_row))
```

But nothing works so far.

Can anyone please give me a hint on how to do this?

The resulting dataframe should look like this:

```
Audio_Filename  Text
sp2_3e2bd3d1-b9fc-095728a4d05b  On a trip to America, he saw people filling hi...
sp1_8248bf61-a66d-81f33aa7212d  When the young officers were told they were go...
sp3_81051730-8a18-6bf476d919a4  Yeah, unbelievable, I had not even thought of ...
```

(Of course, I have much more audio filenames and corresponding texts in the dataframe).

I appreciate any help, thank you!

Comment: what is the criteria of assigning speaker Id are they going to add like `sp2_,sp_1,sp_3,sp_2,sp_1....`?

Comment: The criterion is that the audio file is spoken by a specific speaker, so the audio filename has to match a certain speaker ID.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have `audio_filenames` and `speaker_ids` list, you can use `Series.map` function. For example:

```py
audio_filenames = [
    "3e2bd3d1-b9fc-095728a4d05b",
    "8248bf61-a66d-81f33aa7212d",
    "81051730-8a18-6bf476d919a4",
]
speaker_ids = ["sp2", "sp1", "sp3"]


mapper = {k: "{}_{}".format(v, k) for k, v in zip(audio_filenames, speaker_ids)}
df["Audio_Filename"] = df["Audio_Filename"].map(mapper)

print(df)
```

Prints:

```
                   Audio_Filename                                                                      Text
0  sp2_3e2bd3d1-b9fc-095728a4d05b  On a trip to America, he saw people filling his noodles into paper cups.
1  sp1_8248bf61-a66d-81f33aa7212d           When the young officers were told they were going to the front,
2  sp3_81051730-8a18-6bf476d919a4                       Yeah, unbelievable, I had not even thought of that.
```

Comment: First, thank you kindly for your answer! The code is still running, I'll let you know asap if this worked for me :-)

Comment: Mhh, unfortunately, this gives me back NaNs for all 'Audio_Filename' values.

Comment: @MareikeP Can you please edit your question and put there sample of `audio_filenames` and `speaker_ids` lists?

Comment: Ah , now it works! The NaNs occurred due to a lack of attention on my side, I had to adjust something else. Thank you very much for your solution and help! :-)